# MapView gets small when inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I got CoordinatorLayout with structure similar to this:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap">
            ...
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        ... almost all elements here have scroll|enterAlways|snap scrollflags
        <TabLayout />
    </AppBarLayout
    <ViewPager />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

ViewPager has 2 fragments, first one has just 2 simple TextViews nested in NestedScrollView -> LinearLayout and works perfectly fine.

One of this whole coordinatorLayout feature is collapsible toolbar and a bit more content inside it when scrolling down.

Second one is fragment with google map view inside and behaves weird.

Scenario 1. - Maps fragment has just MapView inside it - Map is full size, however when scrolling down toolbar no longer collapses, instead you scroll inside the map, which is I guess expected, I'm just not sure how to write custom MapView to go around it.

Scenario 2 - MapView is inside LinearLayout which is inside NestedScrollView - Toolbar now collapses when scrolling down, however for some reason it gets really small [image: ScreenShot]

Every element inside that map fragment has match parent sizes.

Full Map fragment:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:id="@+id/details_map_view"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

ViewPager inside CoordinatorLayout has match_parent sizes as well:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/details.viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

Comment: I remember someone posting something about adding `android:fillViewport="true"` to the ScrollView's child (The LinearLayout in your case). I'm not sure about it though.

Answer (score 4):

Use `android:fillViewport="true"` on `NestedScrollView` because it defines whether the `NestedScrollView` should stretch its content to fill the viewport

Comment: This did make the map fill the view. It no longer has the ability to pan vertically unfortunately. I guess some kind of subclassing of MapView will be needed.